# Текст прилип к низу

Tags: html, css, less

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня текст все время у нижнего края, а не сверху, как должно быть?

```css
.about .title {
  height: 120px;
}
.about .title span {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.about .services {
  width: 260px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.about .services .list .list-item {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 50px;
}
.about .services .list .list-item span {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.about .services .list .list-item:first-child {
  background: #6cc437;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="about">
        <div class="services">
            <div class="title">
                <span>Our Services</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-item">
                    <span>Responsive layout</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-item">
                    <span>Best support</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-item">
                    <span>Friendly interface</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-item">
                    <span>Quality service</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-item">
                    <span>Cool solution</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <span>just a random text</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ваш `span` после остальных элементов находится, почему он должен быть сверху?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я не так понял свойство display: inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `.about .services` свойство `float:left;`

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о данном свойстве.